# SpriteKit Fast Movement Frame Rate Drop

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I've been working on a game involving fast movement in SpriteKit.  I've tested and profiled the game removing multiple sections of the game and haven't been able to hold a steady 60 fps.  The frame rate drop causes node movement to stutter.  I decided to set up a simple program to test.  With only 4 nodes on screen moving from left to right there is still a drop in frames running on iPhone 7 Plus.  Is there any way to optimize fast movement in SpriteKit to hold a steady frame rate?

```
import SpriteKit
import GameplayKit

class GameScene: SKScene {

var ship = SKSpriteNode()
var ship2 = SKSpriteNode()
var ship3 = SKSpriteNode()
var ship4 = SKSpriteNode()

override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

    ship.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "Spaceship")
    ship.position = CGPoint(x: -300, y: 0)
    ship.size = CGSize(width: 50, height: 50)
    ship.setScale(1)
    ship.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: ship.size)
    ship.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
    ship.zPosition = 2
    self.addChild(ship)

    ship2.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "Spaceship")
    ship2.position = CGPoint(x: -200, y: -50)
    ship2.size = CGSize(width: 50, height: 50)
    ship2.setScale(1)
    ship2.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: ship.size)
    ship2.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
    ship2.zPosition = 2
    self.addChild(ship2)

    ship3.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "Spaceship")
    ship3.position = CGPoint(x: -100, y: 50)
    ship3.size = CGSize(width: 50, height: 50)
    ship3.setScale(1)
    ship3.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: ship.size)
    ship3.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
    ship3.zPosition = 2
    self.addChild(ship3)

    ship4.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "Spaceship")
    ship4.position = CGPoint(x: -0, y: 100)
    ship4.size = CGSize(width: 50, height: 50)
    ship4.setScale(1)
    ship4.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: ship.size)
    ship4.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
    ship4.zPosition = 2
    self.addChild(ship4)

}

override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event:     UIEvent?) {

}

override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

}


override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {

    // Called before each frame is rendered
    ship.position.x += 15
    ship2.position.x += 15
    ship3.position.x += 15
    ship4.position.x += 15

    if ship.position.x > 800 {
        ship.position.x = -950
    } else if ship2.position.x > 800 {
        ship2.position.x = -900
    } else if ship3.position.x > 800 {
        ship3.position.x = -850
    } else if ship4.position.x > 800 {
        ship4.position.x = -800
    }

}

}
```

Edit: When profiling the test program above the frame rate drops to 59 fps.

Comment: Notning you are showing would cause frame drop

Comment: Are you running on the iPhone 7 simulator or an actual iPhone 7 device? The simulator tends to have performance issues depending on the computer you run it on.

Comment: I'm running this on an iPhone 7 Plus device. When I profile core animation the frame rate fluctuates between 59 and 60 fps.  In the main app I have 40 nodes with 8 draws and the problem is amplified. The frame rate stays between 57-60 fps but causes stuttering.

Comment: Are you updating the nodes' positions in the `override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval)` because if so there's your problem right there. Also make sure to tag whoever you're responding to in the comments so that person gets notified that you responded.